# Form Compatibility - C++

Tags: c++, windows, macos, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gui toolkits, which should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584734/gui-toolkits-which-should-i-use)
>   [What is the best library to use when writing GUI applications in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061877/what-is-the-best-library-to-use-when-writing-gui-applications-in-c)

I wanted to create a program compatible on both Windows and Mac OS X using C++ but I am uncertain of what to use for forms, windows, etc. Would I have to convert the code later on, is there some alternative GUI I can use, or could I even create custom forms using basic C++ code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gui toolkits, which should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584734/gui-toolkits-which-should-i-use) [What is the best library to use when writing GUI applications in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061877/what-is-the-best-library-to-use-when-writing-gui-applications-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very strict about the MVC separation. Implement the view twice: once for Windows API with C++, once for Cocoa with Obj-C. Link as appropriate.

If you don't care about the native look and feel, use Qt as Saif suggested.

Comment: Can't agree with this enough. Enforcing a strict separation is not only a good design practice, it also allows you to create appropriate per-platform interfaces. Native look and feel is exceptionally important for ease of use. Qt just doesn't get this right. I make a long-winded version of the same argument [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5061959/366904).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I didn't recognize the importance of native look until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Qt framework](http://qt.nokia.com). It's cross-platform.